# Html table printing from array

Tags: php, logic

I have a csv in such a format. I am trying to build an html table like show below.

```
  Sem 1 , Subj 1 , 75 , 100 ;
  Sem 1 , Subj 2 , 95 , 100 ;
  Sem 1 , Subj 3 , 88 , 100 ;
  Sem 2 , Subj 2 , 95 , 100 ;
  Sem 2 , Subj 3 , 85 , 100 ;
  Sem 3 , Subj 4 , 87 , 100 ;
  Sem 4 , Subj 1 , 84 , 100 ;
```

HTML Table

```
      Sem 1  Sem 2  Sem 3  Sem 4
Subj 1   75      X     X     84
Subj 2   95     95     X     X 
Subj 3   88     85     X     X 
Subj 4   X      X      87    X
```

// This is what i have came up with . Which is currently printing only the heading

```
$datas = [
["Sem 1" , "Subj 1" , "75" , "100"],
["Sem 1" , "Subj 2" , "95" , "100"],
["Sem 1" , "Subj 3" , "88" , "100"],
["Sem 2" , "Subj 2" , "95" , "100"],
["Sem 2" , "Subj 3" , "85" , "100"],
["Sem 3" , "Subj 4" , "87" , "100"],
["Sem 4" , "Subj 1" , "84" , "100"]];


  
$unique_coloum = [];
echo "<tr>";
foreach($datas as $data){
    if(!in_array($data[0],$unique_coloum)){
        echo "<td>".$data[0]."</td>";
        array_push($unique_coloum,$data[0]);
    }       
}
echo "</tr>";   
foreach($datas as $data){
   #?
}
```

The Sem and Subj are n. I am stuck at for loop logic on how about to start. Any help would be great.

Comment: since this question apparently is about php - ***why*** did you tag C#?

Comment: Restructure your array so that it's organized by subject (subject as key, value another array that hold data for each semester), because subjects present rows and semesters present cells. Output should be trivial after that.

Comment: Please look next solution: https://phpize.online/?phpses=dfb712d066a785d82383e81ffec1f682&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev if you have a solution,  then please actually write an answer on stackoverflow - that's how this site is supposed to work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use next solution:

```
<?php
$datas = [
    ["Sem 1" , "Subj 1" , "75" , "100"],
    ["Sem 1" , "Subj 2" , "95" , "100"],
    ["Sem 1" , "Subj 3" , "88" , "100"],
    ["Sem 2" , "Subj 2" , "95" , "100"],
    ["Sem 2" , "Subj 3" , "85" , "100"],
    ["Sem 3" , "Subj 4" , "87" , "100"],
    ["Sem 4" , "Subj 1" , "84" , "100"]
];

$columns = array_column($datas, 0, 0);

sort($columns);
// var_export($columns);

$res = array_reduce(
    $datas,
    function($res, $data) {
        if (!isset($res[$data[1]])) $res[$data[1]] = [];
        $res[$data[1]][$data[0]] = $data[2];
        return $res;
    },
    $res
);

// var_export($res);

$output = "<tr><th>subject</th>" . implode('</th><th>', $columns) . '</th></tr>' . PHP_EOL;

foreach($res as $key => $row) {
    $output .= "<tr><td>$key</td>";
    foreach($columns as $col) {
        $output .= $row[$col] ? "<td>$row[$col]</td>" : "<td>X</td>";
    }
    $output .= "</tr>" . PHP_EOL;
}

echo $output;
```

[share PHP code](https://phpize.online/?phpses=dfb712d066a785d82383e81ffec1f682&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)